# How to do RATIO function using SOLR Query

Tags: java, sorting, solr, lucene, solrj

Solr query has sort function sort=field order.

In other words i need to sort the field with ratio.
example:
In my solr indexed data i have a field like
sex : m m f m f f f f f f f f

What i need to show the result in ratio format where.it should calculate male and female separately. m is 3 and f is 9.so it should detect it is in 1:3 ratio and display the result as :
m f f f m f f f m f f f
the ratio should always start displaying male first in its ratio..?? please hep me to sort out this.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just index it that way?  Or better yet, index two numeric fields, one with the count of females, one with the count of males?  This seems like a garbage-in-garbage-out scenario.

Comment: Hi femtoRgon, Thanks for your reply. But is it possible to do during query time?

Comment: Are we talking one document with "f" in the field value, then another document with "m" in the field and so on? And you want the documents sorted {f: "m"}, {f: "f"}, {f: "f"}, etc.?

Comment: yes MatsLindh.exactly. Is it possible with solr query rather than writing any java codes??? I have didi this using java but it gets slow during indexing after adding that jar. am new to solr. plz help me out